# Why can I not overrides a JaxxObject?

Tags: java

I am using the JAXX project, and I would like to extend some generated Jaxx file.

But then I got a NPE error when I execute my code

`ERROR [main] (JAXXEngine.java:356) run - java.lang.NullPointerException at jaxx.compiler.tags.DefaultObjectHandler.applyStylesheets(DefaultObjectHandler.java:875)`

JaxxObjectDescriptor is missing because the class is not generated by Jaxx.

Is there a way to fix this ?

thanks.

Comment: The was an issue about (https://forge.nuiton.org/issues/912)? It was closed.

Comment: Yes I saw it, but still the defect is here.